# BrightIdeasSoftware.FastObjectListView.CellEditFinished e.Cancel not working

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I have a listview where a user can double click a cell to edit. I am validating the users input and if its incorrect I don't want the change to be implemented.

Issue is the e.Cancel is not cancelling the event? Is there anything in the properites that needs setting aswell?

```
private void HoursListView_CellEditFinished(object sender, CellEditEventArgs e)
    {
        string originalValue = e.Value.ToString();
        string newValue = e.NewValue.ToString();

        string[] timeSplit = e.NewValue.ToString().Split(':');

        if (!Regex.IsMatch(newValue, @"^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}"))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect hours format!", "Edit Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else if (Convert.ToDouble(timeSplit[0]) > 24)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Hours cannot be over 24!", "Edit Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else if (Convert.ToDouble(timeSplit[1]) > 59)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Minutes value cannot be over 59!", "Edit Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else if (Convert.ToDouble(timeSplit[2]) > 59)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Seconds value cannot be over 59!", "Edit Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);                
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateTotalHoursForTheWeek();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it... Turns out you need to use the event CellEditFinishing not CellEditFinished!